# pyparsing.ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}

Tags: python, rdflib

I am running the following sparql in my code but I get an error.

```
def get_parents_of_node(node):
    sparql = """select ?superclass where {{ 
        :{0} rdfs:subClassOf* ?superclass
    }}""".format(node)
    q = g.query(sparql)
    for row in q:
        print row

get_parents_of_node('http://cccc.com#LaptopHighPerformance')
```

The error message is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Python\RDF Parser\RDF_Parser.py", line 244, in <module>
    get_parents_of_node('http://cccc.com#LaptopHighPerformance')
  File "C:\Code\Python\RDF Parser\RDF_Parser.py", line 68, in get_parents_of_node
    q = g.query(sparql)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1085, in query
    query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\processor.py", line 74, in query
    parsetree = parseQuery(strOrQuery)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\parser.py", line 1058, in parseQuery
    return Query.parseString(q, parseAll=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1632, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery} (at char 36), (line:2, col:9)
[Finished in 3.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Code\Python\RDF Parser\RDF_Parser.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html#prepared-queries), you are supposed to pass values (with the appropriate type) in using the `initBindings` argument to map the desired query variable to a specific value when calling [`query`](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph.query).  For example:

```
def get_parents_of_node(node):
    sparql = """select ?superclass where {{ 
        ?class rdfs:subClassOf* ?superclass
    }}"""
    q = g.query(sparql, initBindings={'class': rdflib.URIRef(node)})
    for row in q:
        print row
```

This assumes of course the node is indeed a URI reference.

Comment: Tried that and I still getting the same error. The node is a reference

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and missed the most important portion. I updated the answer with what `initBindings` should actually contain.